# No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2003, but it is registered

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, dialect

How to fix this error?

**No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2003**

Here is my dialect class - child entity does not have fields, related to the error

```
public class CustomPostgreSQL10Dialect extends PostgreSQL10Dialect {
    public CustomPostgreSQL10Dialect() {
        super();
        this.registerHibernateType(2003, "sql_array_type");
    }
}
```

and single properties file

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=io.alphaminds.base.hibernate.dialect.CustomPostgreSQL10Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=io.alphaminds.base.hibernate.dialect.CustomPostgreSQL10Dialect
```

Spring 2.5.2

And my entity

```
@TypeDef(
        name = "enum-array",
        typeClass = EnumArrayType.class
)
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public abstract class Contact extends AuditedEntity {
    //...
    @Type(type = "enum-array", parameters = @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
            name = "sql_array_type", value = "messengers"))
    MessengerType[] messengers;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to register the SQL type by calling `registerColumnType` in the `Dialect`, although I don't think this is what you really want, as that would use a single SQL type for all enum arrays. You should provide the SQL type at the use-site through `@Column(columnDefinition = "int[]")`